# sending a variable into scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select in my form. When I change it "change function" assign that value to **vardir** variable. I want to send this variable into **uploadFile** scope but it doesn't recognize variable(empty) but afterUploadAll function alert show true value of the variable.

How can I send a variable into scope? Thank you

```
  var vardir = "";
  $("#galeri").live("change",function(event) {
      if ( $("#galeri").val() != '') {
          $("#yukletr").show("slow");
          vardir = $("#galeri").val();
      }
      else
        $("#yukletr").hide("slow");
  });

  $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
    url:"upload.php",
    multiple:true,
    method:'POST',
    formData: { dir: vardir },
    allowedTypes : "png,jpeg,jpg,gif",
    afterUploadAll:function()
    {
        alert(vardir);
    }
  });
```

Comment: When you are calling `.uploadFile` and pass the object with `vardir`, that variable doesn't have a value yet. This has **nothing** to do with scope and *everything* to do with timing.

Comment: When's the file upload meant to run? Currently, it runs as soon as you execute the code, which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: could you post your html code as well?

Comment: @Genus: It doesn't _matter_ what the HTML code is, as it's an issue with the code itself.

Comment: I need to pass gallery id (which is comes from select dom) into scope. How can I send a variable into scope. thats the question.

Comment: @algkmn: could you explain what you're trying to do with your file upload, and when is it meant to run? The issue doesn't seem to be a matter of scope.

Comment: @algkmn: Did you read [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897639/sending-a-variable-into-scope#comment33161403_21897639) at all? Here is the most important part: *"This has **nothing** to do with scope and everything to do with timing."*. So no, the question is **not** "how to send a variable into scope", but "when to run `.uploadFile`".

Comment: This issue is that the 'uploadFile' function is not called in the correct context.  i need to be called immediately after vardir is set during the click event handler, but its outside of the handler's scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue. there is a dynamicFormData function like;

```
dynamicFormData: function() { 
  var data ={ dir: $("#galeri").val() } 
  return data; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the upload function right after the change event is triggered:

```
    var vardir = "";
$("#galeri").live("change",function(event) {
        if ( $("#galeri").val() != '') {
            $("#yukletr").show("slow");
            vardir = $("#galeri").val();
            // relocated here!
            $("#fileuploader").uploadFile({
                url:"upload.php",
                multiple:true,
                method:'POST',
                formData: { dir: vardir },
                allowedTypes : "png,jpeg,jpg,gif",
                afterUploadAll:function()
                {
                    alert(vardir);
                }
            });
        }
        else
            $("#yukletr").hide("slow");
});
```

Comment: This might not be intended, especially if one makes a typo or accidentally leaves the focus of the input.

Comment: it's working but every select option change it calls uploadfile function that is append a new file select box. Now I can't use this solution :/

Comment: I can't use scope in "change function" and I can't send a variable into scope. How I can solve this issue?

Comment: @algkmn: Why do keep saying your problem is scope? I (and others) [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897639/sending-a-variable-into-scope/21897802#comment33161403_21897639) [twice already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897639/sending-a-variable-into-scope/21897802#comment33161769_21897639), that your problem has **nothing** to do with scope.